# Can I contribute to a question (through an answer) without the right to comment?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

I have seen quite the number of questions on GameDev SE where I wanted to post some information like a link to other questions or some info I had gathered for that question.

However, I'm quite new to Gamedev SE and therefor I have not yet unlocked the ability to comment. Therefor in nearly all cases, I decided not to post my findings or links as an actual Answer, as they are no real answer but more of a suggestion or addition to the OP's question / problem which *might* help them in their search for an answer.

**Question**

What do I do in these situations, where I feel like I have some information that the OP could use?

I feel that this is something comments would be used for (?), but it feels bad to have info but not be able to share it because my reputation is too low.

**Note:** I am aware that this post might be self-answering as 'wait till you can use comments' seems the most likely answer to me. The question can be closed if this is the case. (feedback on what taggs this post should have is appreciated aswell)

Comment: You're not far from earning commenting privileges, so I'd recommend keeping a list of posts you want to comment on. A couple upvotes from now you'll be free to go ahead and post them. As an aside, thank you for asking first rather than trying to circumvent the system! I think this helps produce higher-quality Q&A in the long run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please don't.

In the case that you haven't generated enough rep to post a comment (50) - but you have enough to speak in chat (20) - you can use the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) and ask someone else to post a comment for you.

Comment: Thats a useful answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Getting your answers upvoted one of the fastest ways to increase your reputation (+10 rep per upvote).

I suggest you build nice, full-fledged answers around the input you want to share with the OP, as long as the answer actually answers the question.

Writing good answers will get you the rep you need in no time!